# In a dataframe how do I select a column and convert the value to a float?

Tags: python, pandas, int

I have a dateframe how can I convert Col2 to from a float to int?

df input

```
 Col1    Col2     Col3
 1       2.0      3.0
 3       3.0      0.9
 3       1.0      1.3
 4       nan      1.3
```

df output

```
 Col1    Col2     Col3
 1       2        3.0
 3       3        0.9
 3       1        1.3
 4       nan      1.3
```

I tried int() but couldn't get it to work for my dataframe.

Comment: `df.loc[:, 'Col2'] = df['Col2'].astype(int)`

Comment: You cannot store NaN's in an integer array. Either drop them, or fill them with a value.

Comment: Fill nan first, then covert the dtype. df = df.fillna(0)
    df['Col2'] = df['Col2'].astype(int)